# How can I create an SSIS package which loops through excel files with a specific keyword in their name?

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I am creating an SSIS package which needs to selectively loop through excel files in a folder that contain a specific keyword in their name (the keyword can appear anywhere in the name). This folder will include multiple files that do not include this keyword.

Bonus: I then need to use that same file name to create a date variable in SSIS (the file name will have the required components to create the date inside it). So far my efforts have failed, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For anyone who stumbles on this and is looking to solve the bonus question, I ended up solving it using a filename variable that was created by my foreach loop. That variable was then passed to a script task along with the current year (set dynamically by Year(getdate())). I used the C# string.contains function to check what date the filename string contained and wrote that to a variable. The following is a picture of the C# script for reference. https://i.gyazo.com/196fe4d2756551265e058a00d1c3f960.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Foreach File Loop Enumertor. In the FileSpec, use a wildcard, such as:

`*SearchString*.csv` or `*SearchString*.xslx`

You will probably want to select the Filename and Extension radio button. Map that to an SSIS package variable.

For the bonus, you can create another package variable with an expression based on the mapped variable and perform whatever string parsing you need in order to extract information from the file name.

Comment: Is there a guide you would suggest towards starting to set this up? I am not very familiar with the Foreach File Loop Enumerator.

Comment: @CameronDavis Take a look at this and let me know if you have any questions. https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/803195/Foreach-File-Enumerator-in-SSIS-2

Comment: Good answer. I find that full file path is most useful so you can map to file path expression of the file path

Comment: I have been working on the problem, I seem to have created a loop through the files in a folder but despite my filename variable changing the data is from the same file.

Comment: Okay, a response to my last comment turns out it was an issue with the add-on I am using in excel (Cozyroc Excel Plus). I will return with any further updates

Comment: Update: This solution worked! I haven't been able to get the bonus working but that has more to do with my inexperience when it comes to SSIS string functions.

Comment: @CameronDavis No worries. Happy to help. Good luck.